# Add a different attribute value to images, Drupal Twig

Tags: drupal, twig

I want to add a different attribute value to each image, So that Image one has an attribute of image-1, Image 2 has an attribute of image-2, and so on.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am new to Drupal and have no idea where to start. 
I can add a single attribute to all the images.

This is how my image.html.twig currently looks like:

```
<img{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}/>
```

This is what I am trying to achive:

```
<img src="path to image" onclick="currentSlide(1)"
<img src="path to image" onclick="currentSlide(2)"
<img src="path to image" onclick="currentSlide(3)"
```

I got as far as this:

```
<img src="path to image" onclick="currentSlide(1)"
<img src="path to image" onclick="currentSlide(1)"
<img src="path to image" onclick="currentSlide(1)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how you can add different attributes

```
<img{{ attributes.setAttribute('onclick', 'currentSlide(1)') }}/>
```